# How should I write the rule so that it looks like this?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to convert url. It leads to the index page.

the constant I define
`define("URL_PAGE", "page.php?p=");`

link:
`<a class="menu-link" href="'.BASE_URL.URL_PAGE.$row1['page_slug'].'">';`

.htaccess
`RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)$/?$         page.php?p=$1       [NC,L]`

result:
http://localhost/aione/page.php?p=about-us

I'm trying to catch the incoming link like this.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['p']))
{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Check the page slug is valid or not.
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mbo_page WHERE page_slug=? AND status=?");
    $statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['p'],'Active'));
    $total = $statement->rowCount();
    if( $total == 0 )
    {
        header('location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

How should I write the rule so that it looks like this? Your help is appreciated.
http://localhost/aione/page/about-us

Comment: You should use `$_GET['p']`

Comment: I have tried with it too.

Comment: @Tajni it doesn't matter in this case, `$_GET['p'] === $_REQUEST['p']` by default. See: [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: @burakios Please describe what exactly happens when you open the `http://localhost/aione/page/about-us`, do you get a redirect to `index.php`, a 404, a 403, a 500, or anything else?

You should monitor the network request via **F12** → **Network** tab and update your question. -- Please see: [this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=how+to+use+network+tab+in+chrome+OR+firefox)

Comment: @DavidRefoua, I know, but it should be used `$_GET` in the sake of clarity of code.

Comment: @Tajni I agree with you on that note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a trivial question.

#### Try this:

```
<a class="menu-link" href="'.BASE_URL.'page/'.$row1['page_slug'].'">';
```

Or, you can try this instead:

```
define("URL_PAGE", "page/");
```

---

Your `.htaccess` file needs to look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/*page/([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] #If static R=301
</IfModule>
```

Place `.htaccess` in the same directory (i.e. folder) as `page.php`.  (e.g. in `http://localhost/aione/`)

#### Notes:

- **`^/*page/([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1`** **only** works with the following style: "http://localhost/aione/page/about-us", if you want something like `about-us/test` to also be passed as `page.php?id=about-us/test`, use the following rule:
- **`^/*page/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1`** **also** matches for something like "http://localhost/aione/page/about-us/test/link", and it will rewrite to: `page.php?id=about-us/test/link`, meaning the following:

```php
$_GET['id'] === 'about-us/test/link'; // true
```

as always, remember to validate and sanitize any user input.

Comment: I have already tried them many times in different ways.Do you have any idea what I should write to the .htaccess file?

Comment: @burakios Sure, I updated my answer for details on `.htaccess`.  I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the update. but I still haven't caught it. What am I doing wrong? Can you check the code I just added?

Comment: @burakios Please describe what is currently happening concisely, so it'd be possible to better help you.

Comment: It shouldn't have been that hard. I'm missing something but couldn't find it:)
here is the page page it is trying to load:
https://ibb.co/p0hXLBT

but it looks like an invalid link:
https://ibb.co/3fCb5vd

Comment: @burakios Please also upload a screenshot of your expected results (e.g. is it the `assets` not loading that is the issue?)

Comment: @burakios, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223050/discussion-between-david-refoua-and-burakios).